# Cannot save NAs to SQL DB using R and RJDBS

Tags: sql, r

I noticed that I cannot save NAs to my DB, where price is a `float` variable. I found that changing column type to double will help, however, it did not help. The sam issue for `varchar` variables.

```
dbSendUpdate(CONNECTION,paste("INSERT INTO DB  (Price) values (",
 paste("'",NA,"'", sep=""),
 ");"))
```

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :    execute JDBC update query
> failed in dbSendUpdate ([Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Invalid syntax
> for float: "NA")

How can I export data showing NAs as empty cells in the DB?

Comment: You need to convert NA to a valid float value e.g. NULL or 0 (zero)

Comment: I tried 'NULL' (and 'Inf'), but the same error appeared. Replacing with other numbers is dangerous as a variable can get any value.

Comment: Hi - are you putting single quotes round NA (and NULL)? If you are then that's not going to work as that will convert these values to strings

Comment: If I simply put NA (without paste function and quotes), I have the following error ERROR: Column "NA" does not exist